# How can I override the functionality of laravel's "script" and "style" functions?

Tags: laravel, minify

I basically have this in various places in my code:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/someFile.css') }}
```

As well as:

```
{{ HTML::script('js/someFile.js') }}
```

Now, the problem is I might have several of these. I want a way that I can override all of these with one "super" function that will combine all the CSS files into one, and the JS into one. Basically, i want to write my own file combining logic.

How would I go about hooking into the "style" and "script" functions so that I can create a new function that prints out the css and js as one? I know how to write the logic, but I need to know how to override those two functions?

Comment: Would something like `grunt` or `gulp` or Laravel package `barryvdh/assetic` https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-assetic suit your needs?

Answer (score 3):

You may use [CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline#introduction-to-directives). This package will automatically combine all of your assets (`css/js`) into a single file and also it'll `minify` the code into one single file.

This means that, the browser will make only a single request and also the size of the file could be reduced as well.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to change the laravel HTML::script & HTML::style method. You can do this by going to:

```
/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Html/HtmlBuilder.php
```

In this file the HTML builder methods are specified (style, script, image, link etc.)
To modify the script/style methods scroll down till you see:

```
/**
 * Generate a link to a JavaScript file.
 *
 * @param  string  $url
 * @param  array   $attributes
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return string
 */
public function script($url, $attributes = array(), $secure = null)
{
    $attributes['src'] = $this->url->asset($url, $secure);

    return '<script'.$this->attributes($attributes).'></script>'.PHP_EOL;
}

/**
 * Generate a link to a CSS file.
 *
 * @param  string  $url
 * @param  array   $attributes
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return string
 */
public function style($url, $attributes = array(), $secure = null)
{
    $defaults = array('media' => 'all', 'type' => 'text/css', 'rel' => 'stylesheet');

    $attributes = $attributes + $defaults;

    $attributes['href'] = $this->url->asset($url, $secure);

    return '<link'.$this->attributes($attributes).'>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

As you can see this is exactly what the methods does. You said you know how to write the logic, so here you can edit it.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I can override those, but how? How do I tell Laravel to run MY script function, instead of theirs?

Comment: By editing this code, this the Laravel's code. If you edit it Laravels functions will no longer work but it will use yours. Put your code for script in the script method and your code for style in the style method